# Strange behaviour with the Stack Exchange network while on VPN

Tags: support, 408-timeout

- Sometimes while on my office VPN, I am not able to access any of the Stack Exchange sites, while I am able to access everything else.
- This happens once in a while, not everytime. When it happens, I try to open [stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com) and the page does not load, instead times out after some time.
- I tried to ask the IT group whether these group of sites was blocked, and it isn't so.
- Sometimes reconnecting to VPN resolves the issue.

I am puzzled, and don't understand why this could happen.

Is there a series of diagnostics that I can try next time I see this behaviour to understand what is happening?

Comment: Can you ping? Can you ping the IP (in case it is a DNS problem)? Can you run a traceroute or similar?

Comment: Will check and post here the next time this happens.