# Stack Overflow is apparently blocking my office by IP?

Tags: support

I am unable to access Stack Overflow from my office through the gateway `182.72.213.121`.

My network team says that the IP is blocked from your side.

Could you please unblock our access, as we are immensely dependant on your website for our queries.

The trace route is completing to 64.34.119.12 from my unblocked network. When I try through my blocked gateway I can get to gwny01.stackoverflow.com [64.34.41.58] and there is a request time out after that which is supposed to be response from 64.34.119.12 . This shows that I am able to bypass into the SO network but being blocked from 64.34.119.12 ( server) I suppose . Is there a way to unblock this access.

Comment: At the risk of being unfair: Most likely, some of the queries from your office brought about the block. Something to think about....

Comment: Please define: `blocked`.

Comment: Try tracerouting from your office to SO, this will show exactly where your being blocked, maybe its the ISP for your office, or a bad route, or a dns cache flush is in order.  Can you or your network team provide specific details as to why they believe its on the SO side?

Comment: @Mobinga - If the office stops functioning because they can't ask on SO I think its a problem that they charge for their services...

Comment: There's depend "nice-to-have resource" and depend "can't work without". And then there's also depend "I need my fix of answering and editing" but that's not an issue for everyone.

Comment: @MPelletier, I'm with you on that last point, I need my daily fix of SO :)

Comment: I have seen some strange behavior with the SE network too. I tried to explain it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93932/135875), but hardly anyone has paid attention. There is *some* issue definitely with this site, we just don't know what.

Comment: In the event that you are _not_ blocked, a traceroute would be immensely helpful.

Comment: @Lazer: maybe if you provided the information that was asked for in the comment to your question, people would have investigated more.

Comment: @Mat: That info was asked 1 hour ago **after** I added this comment here.

Comment: The trace route is completing to 64.34.119.12 from my unblocked network .. When i try through my blocked gateway i can get to  gwny01.stackoverflow.com [64.34.41.58] and there is a request time out after that which is supposed to be response from 64.34.119.12 . this shows that i am able to bypass into the SO network but being blocked from 64.34.119.12 ( server)  i suppose . Is there a way to unblock this access .

Comment: @JazinEbrahim, you need to buy a bazooka and take a tour of your company to take care of the guilty culprit(s) who've been spamming SO - presumably multiple times from different accounts. Of course, if *you yourself* are the culprit, the bazooka may prove impractical.

Comment: @benjol , i got hold of the guys who were behind this , Any way thnx to SO , its unblocked now .